# How to pre fill fields in a form when using django-bootstrap-modal-forms

Tags: python, django

I am using django-bootstrap-modal-forms and it works perfectly as in documentation when using fields form my model. Some of the fields are ForeignKeys and they are displayed properly for user to select a value from database table that is referenced by the key, but instead of that I need to put username of the current user.

I tried to change how the CreateView class handles fields, but with no luck. Probably doing something wrong.

models.py

```py
class userSchoolYear(models.Model):
    user_in_school = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey(sifMusicSchool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_year = models.ForeignKey(sifSchoolYear, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_year_grade = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=IZBOR_RAZREDA, default=None, null=True)
    user_instrument = models.ForeignKey(instType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    user_profesor = models.ForeignKey(profSchool, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

views.py

```py
class SchoolYearCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'school_year.html'
    form_class = SchoolYearForm
    success_message = 'Success!'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('school')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form_class.user_in_school = 'johnny'  ### HERE
        print(user.username)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```py
class SchoolYearForm(BSModalForm):

    class Meta:
            model = userSchoolYear
            fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the author Uroš Trstenjak I was able to find a solution. I was wrong trying to set field values from views.py, instead it should be done in forms.py. So, basically I had to write a **init** for the form and alter fields values. Uroš pointed out that at from level I can get current user from self.request.user and it did work.